# How to add custom attributes for custom components in jsf?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, custom-component

I am creating the  custom component like below code in taglib.xml in JSF

```
     <tag-name>CustomComponent</tag-name>
   <component>
            <component-type>javax.faces.Input</component-type> 
    </component>
      </tag>
```

rendering the component in **xhtml** like below

```
<h:body bgcolor="white">
<cs:CustomComponent></cs:CustomComponent>       
            </h:body>
```

I want to add the **custom Attributes for this component**. And want to throw warning if any other arguments given other than i specified. Is this possible with jsf.

Answer (score 1):

Look here

```
<tag>
<tag-name>training</tag-name>
<attribute>
    <name>style</name>
</attribute>
<attribute>
    <name>action</name>
    <method-signature>java.lang.String action()</method-signature>
</attribute>
<component>
    <component-type>training</component-type>
    <renderer-type>pl.spiid.app.spiidcharts.beans.training.Training</renderer-type>
</component>
```

In xhtml I can use `<libtag:training style="blabla" />` and I can retrieve it in Renderer:

```
    Map<String, Object> attrMap = component.getAttributes(); // to 
    String style = (String) attrMap.get("style");
```